# c++ Search for char in char function?

Tags: c++

I have googled a lot to search for a solution, but non so far!
I need to search in a char variable for a certain char to match.

```
 char SOMECHAR[] = { 0XC1, 0XC2, 0XD4, 0XD3 };
    if (strchr(SOMECHAR, '0xD3') == NULL) {
// i did not find it!
   }
```

`strstr` does not work, `strchar` does not work, ant other solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: You want to search in a `char` variable for a `char`? That doesn't make sense, do you mean a `char*`? Also, the code you have is ill-formed as `char` is a type.

Comment: @Patratel Please show the function definition.

Comment: @TartanLlama oops, sorry i meant:  if (strchr(SOMECHAR, '0xD3') == NULL)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - HERE YOU GO! :)

Comment: You are confusing the character literal `'0xD3'` with the value 0xD3. Plus `SOMECHAR` should be null terminated if you're going to pass it to `strchr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to be careful with using values that high with signed `char`s.
For example, `0xD3 == (char)0xD3` is not true, whereas `0xD3 == (unsigned char)0xD3` is.

An example with `std::find`:

```
char SOMECHAR[] { 0x31, 0xC2, 0xD4, 0xD3 };
auto loc = std::find(std::begin(SOMECHAR), std::end(SOMECHAR), (char)0xD3);
std::cout << "Found at " << std::distance(std::begin(SOMECHAR),loc) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Just a note: the `strchr()` function converts the argument it's searching for to a `char` and `memcmp()` treats the values they're dealing with as `unsigned char` regardless of whether or not `char` is signed.  So those functions do not have the problem you're warning about.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) `'0xD3'` is not same thing as `0xD3` or `'\xD3'` which are the values you probably really want to use.

2) You need to null terminate `SOMECHAR` for `strchr()` to be well-defined in the situation where the character is not found.  Alternatively, you can use `memchr()` and pass in the size of the `SOMECHAR` array.

So:

```
char SOMECHAR[] = { 0XC1, 0XC2, 0XD4, 0XD3, 0 };

if (strchr(SOMECHAR, 0xD3) == NULL) {
    // i did not find it!
}
```

or

```
char SOMECHAR[] = { 0XC1, 0XC2, 0XD4, 0XD3 };

if (memchr(SOMECHAR, 0xD3, sizeof(SOMECHAR)) == NULL) {
    // i did not find it!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

const char *s = "Patratel";

if ( const char *p = std::strchr( s, 't' ) )
{
    std::cout << "Character 't' is found at position " << p - s << std::endl;
}
```

If the character array does not contain a string then you can use standard function `memchr`

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

char SOMECHAR[] = { '\xC1', '\xC2', '\xD4', '\xD3' };

if ( char * p = ( char * )std::memchr( SOMECHAR, '\xD3', sizeof( SOMECHAR ) ) )
{
    std::cout << "Character 't' is found at position " << p - SOMECHAR << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks Vlad, but i cannot use const char *, since my var is defined as char only, and i cannot cast it cause it will crash ...

Comment: @Patratel; If the variable has type char then you can simply compare  if with the equality operator if ( c == 't' ) { /*...*/ }

Comment: `'0xD3'` should be `0xD3`.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious It is the result of "copy and paste". TC is unable even to write at least one line correctly.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - sarcasm ? I really am able to write :) i put '' because this is how google examples shows for string compare. Thanks for the help.